# What is difference between starting with "./" and starting with "/" in a HTML url?

Tags: html, path

What is the difference between:

```
<img src="./cat.png">
```

and

```
<img src="/cat.png">
```

Comment: the preceding dot means it is a relative path , ```/cat.png``` means the absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

As Wu Xiliang stated in the comments `./cat.png` means that it is a relative path, while `/cat.png` means the absolute path.

An **absolute path** is the full address(or location) of the directory to locate to a certain directory or file in the computer. However, a **relative path** is when the address of the current directory is used to locate another directory or file.